# Why is terminal crashing when I should be getting an error message?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, zsh

My apologies if this is an overly nooby question. I'm just learning Ruby and my terminal has started acting funny and I'm not sure how to fix it. I appreciate any guidance that can steer me in the right direction.

First, when I open terminal within VS Code I have started to get the following message - "complete:13: command not found: compdef". As a newcomer, I am not very skilled yet with zsh and not sure what to do to fix this message.

Second, ever since this message started appearing, whenever I run ruby code and expect an error, instead of getting an error message, the terminal just seems to crash. The cursor moves to the next line and then nothing happens other than the fan speeding up. I can type text but the only way to get the terminal working again is to close out and reopen. Is this related to the compdef message I am getting or is this a separate message? Does anyone know how I might go about fixing this? It's preventing me from being able to learn where I am going wrong in my code.

Thank you so much to anyone that may have an answer!

Comment: this page maybe help? https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/3356

Comment: Your problem is not about ruby. The `compdef` error is in the Zsh domain (http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html). By the way if you want to exit the program without closing terminal you can press `Ctrl+C` in the command line

Comment: @realcrispybacon : The problem may in particular be related to the interaction of vscode and zsh, so these two tags would be related to your question. I don't know anything about _vscode_  and what "terminal" means in the context of vscode, but my feeling is that you would see the same behaviour when running, i.e., python. Can you just "open" a terminal with no code being run, and see how it behaves?

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for your responses. So I'm learning you can ignore the VS Code/Ruby aspect of my question. I believe it is a zsh/command line issue. If I open up a new terminal on my mac, the following automatically pops up: "complete:13: command not found: compdef". From the links above it looks like something is going on with my zsh files. I will dig through these resources and see if i can't identify exactly what the problem is. I'm still learning about shells and command line so a lot of it is going over my head but I'll report back with any success I have. Thanks again!

Comment: @realcrispybacon : In this case, you should open a new question describing the new problem. BTW, your error message sounds a bit as if the shell being run were bash and not zsh.